# Copy one db diagram from one db to another on different servers? (Same db)

Tags: sql-server-2005, import

I used the copy database wizard to copy my database from our test server to our production server, the database copied everything fine except for the diagram.

Okay no problem, first I make sure the target database on production has the support objects created to use database diagraming. Then I select to import data from the other database and chose the dbo.sysdiagrams.Go through with the rest of the import data wizard, but then I get the following error:

```
 Validating (Error)
 Messages
 Error 0xc0202049: Data Flow Task: Failure inserting into the read-only column "diagram_id".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

 Error 0xc0202045: Data Flow Task: Column metadata validation failed.
  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

 Error 0xc004706b: Data Flow Task: "component "Destination - sysdiagrams" (31)" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

 Error 0xc004700c: Data Flow Task: One or more component failed validation.
  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

 Error 0xc0024107: Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.
  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

So apparently it didn't like that. What's the problem? I am pretty beginner in SQL Server and only do stuff via the GUI usually so am not sure what to do at this point.

The databases are the same, but on different servers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out, you need to click on the mappings button after you select the dbo.sysdiagrams, and then check the box that says 'allow identity inserts'.